# What is the difference between "" and <> when a header file is included in a program?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

I would like to know what's the difference between

```
#include "stdio.h"
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: Must be a duplicate, surely ?

Comment: @Paul R: You could have found that out in about 5 seconds with the search box.

Comment: @JeremyP: evidently my Google Fu is weak this morning, as I had actually tried and failed to find any of what I am sure must be numerous duplicates. But many congratulations on finding one yourself.

Comment: @Paul R: I used the search box on this site, not Google. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: @JeremyP: I never seem to have much luck with the SO search box, I normally just Google for `<search terms> site:stackoverflow.com` and that seems to be more effective. But evidently not in this case (probably because Google doesn't like `<>` and `""` as search terms).

Answer (score 18):

Use `<whatever>` for system headers, and `"whatever"` for your own headers.

The difference is that when it's enclosed in quotes, the compiler will look in the local directory, but with `<>`, it won't. If you want to get technical, the C standard doesn't guarantee that, but it's how essentially all compilers work.

Answer (score 9):

`""` searches in current file's path.
`<>` searches in global include paths.

Edit: You asked for absolute path and relative path.

Assume you have a file structure as follows:

```
folderX
 -fileX.a
 -fileX.b
 -folderX.Y
  -fileX.Y.a
  -fileX.Y.b
 -folderX.Z
  -fileX.Z.a
```

Then, the absolute path of `fileX.Z.a` would be `folderX/folderX.Z/fileX.Z.a`, assuming that `folderX` is the topmost directory available. The relative path of `fileX.Z.a` relative to e.g. `fileX.a` is just the part `folderX.Z/fileX.Z.a`, i.e. you start the path in the directory where `fileX.a` lies.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <file>
```

This variant is used for system header files. It searches for a file named file in a standard list of system directories. You can prepend directories to this list with the `-I' option.

```
#include "file"
```

This variant is used for header files of your own program. It searches for a file named file first in the directory containing the current file, then in the same directories used for .

The argument of `#include`, whether delimited with quote marks or angle brackets, behaves like a string constant in that comments are not recognized, and macro names are not expanded. Thus, #include  specifies inclusion of a system header file named `x/*y'.

However, if backslashes occur within filename, they are considered ordinary text characters, not escape characters. None of the character escape sequences appropriate to string constants in C are processed.

[Reference](http://www.gnu-m68hc11.org/doc/cpp_2.html):